# What could delay the handshake between a Jenkins server and an SSL SVN server (neither has internet access)?

Tags: performance, svn, jenkins, ssl-certificate, firewall

We have a VM (in a VMWare cluster) running Jenkins (1.477, 1.480.3, and 1.508) to do builds for commits to our SVN repository (Collabnet SVN 1.7.5-3150.92).  The repository is accessed via an SSL connection.  For security reasons neither computer (the build server or the SVN server) have access to the internet.  When a Jenkins build begins the start of the SVN update the console for the job pauses on Updating "https://vcfs01.redacted-address.com/svn/MTCM/Trunk" for 30 - 90 seconds.  Once the update begins it is fairly fast.

To rule Jenkins out as the culprit, I reproduced the same issue by doing a check-out from the build server using TortoiseSVN.  The same delay occurs with Tortoise, and once files begin to transfer the transfer rate ranges from 50 - 70 KB/s (which is great).

We use Kaspersky, and have ruled it out as an issue, because the problem does not occur on programmers PCs that have Kaspersky.  We also tried excluding both servers just to be %100 sure.

For awhile I was convinced this was an issue with certificate revocation checking because I saw with WireShark an attempted HTTP GET from http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/disallowedcertstl.cab?dca976bb02bdc2e3 .  Using the steps in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2677070) I disabled certificate revocation checks on both the the Jenkins server and the SVN server (though I doubt the latter mattered).  Once I made this change I no longer so attempted connections to the windowsupdate server but instead saw an HTTP GET from http://crl.globalsign.com/gs/gsorganizationvalg2.crl .   I stumbled across [this article on disabling CRL checking](http://www.page-house.com/blog/2009/04/how-to-disable-crl-checking.html).  I followed the steps there for both server and no longer see HTTP GETs to foreign (internet) addresses.

When the Jenkins server has access to the internet the handshake takes ~5 seconds in Tortoise (as opposed to ~90 seconds when the firewall prevents access).  Despite the fast handshake for Tortoise the speed for Jenkins is the same as when the firewall was in place!

I did some research on Jenkins (I also updated Jenkins from version 1.477 to 1.508) and found [an article about SVNKit having problems with symbolic links](http://wiki.svnkit.com/SVNKit_FAQ#Q:_I.27m_encountering_performance_issues_refreshing_a_working_copy_accessed_through_a_symbolic_link.).  As far as I can tell, no symbolic links are being used.

What I am seeing with WireShark is that there is some initial activity (creation of an encrypted connection) between the Jenkins server and SVN server.  After the initial activity ~30 seconds passes and then there is more activity (application data is sent).  After the application data there is another ~30 second delay, and then more application data is sent, the encrypted connection is reset, and the update begins.

I talked to the networking group about what @Chris and @Barmar wrote and the networking group said:

> Our DNS servers already have a reverse 168.192 look up zone and it is populated with
>   quite a few servers. I have rarely ever had to do anything with these zones with 
>   the exception of searching for old rogue entries of internal servers.

I assume that means it's not a lookup issue, but I'm over my head here.  Here is a filtered capture between the Jenkins machine (172.25.2.106) and the SVN server (172.25.2.106) that shows the pauses between packet transmission:

[image: WireShark Trace]

Both of these are Win2K8 R2 Datacenter VMware machines.  According to our networking group the DNS entries / lookups for these servers are configured and working correctly.

Comment: Sounds like the server is doing some sort of reverse DNS lookup when the connection is made, which is timing out after 30 seconds or so and then everything gets moving. I see this all the time with new SSH installations on servers with no or minimal internet access.

Comment: That would be my initial guess as well. Set up a local DNS server that serves the reverse domain of your private address block. You don't need any names in it, just an empty 168.192.in-addr.arpa zone.

Comment: I'll ask our networking group about the DNS idea and post the results.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network group noticed these machines are VMs and VMTools was not installed.  They have now installed VMTools.  Performance seemed the same at first, but now an update takes ~30 seconds (still worse than Tortoise but better than originally).

Answer (score 4):

**Issue:** After invoking SVN on the command line on a firewalled server, nothing visible happens for 15 seconds, then the program quits with the following error:

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'SVN.REPOSITORY.REDACTED'

svn: E730054: Error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

**Investigation:** Internet research on the above errors did not uncover any pertinent information.

Process Tracing (procmon) showed a connection attempt to an Akamai (cloud services) server after the SSL/TLS handshake to the SVN Server. The hostname for the server was not shown in Process tracing. Reverse DNS lookup showed a184-51-112-88.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com or a184-51-112-80.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com as the hostname, and the IP was either 184.51.112.88 or 184.51.112.80 (2 entries in DNS cache).

Packet capture tool (MMA) showed a connection attempt to the hostname ctldl.windowsupdate.com after the SSL/TLS Handshake to the SVN server.

The windows Crypto API was attempting to connect to Windows Update to retrieve Certificate revocation information (CRL – certificate revocation list). The default timeout for CRL retrieval is 15 seconds. The timeout for authentication on the server is 10 seconds; as 15 is greater than 10, this fails.

**Resolution:** Internet research uncovered the following: (also see picture at bottom)

Solution 1: Decrease CRL timeout Group Policy -> Computer Config ->Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Public Key Policies -> Certificate Path Validation Settings -> Network Retrieval  – see picture below.

https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=470698

support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2625048

blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/05/14/3409948.aspx

Solution 2: Open firewall for CRL traffic

support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2677070

Solution 3: SVN command line flags (untested)

serverfault.com/questions/716845/tortoise-svn-initial-connect-timeout - 
alternate svn command line flag solution.

**Additional Information:** Debugging this issue was particularly difficult. SVN 1.8 disabled support for the Neon HTTP RA (repository access) library in favor of the Serf library which removed client debug logging. [1] In addition, the SVN error code returned did not match the string given in svn_error_codes.h [2] Also, SVN Error codes cannot be mapped back to their ENUM label easily, this case SVN error code E170013 maps to SVN_ERR_RA_CANNOT_CREATE_SESSION.

1. stackoverflow.com/questions/8416989/is-it-possible-to-get-svn-client-debug-output
2. people.apache.org/~brane/svndocs/capi/svn__error__codes_8h.html#ac8784565366c15a28d456c4997963660a044e5248bb3a652768e5eb3105d6f28f
3. code.google.com/archive/p/serf/issues/172

**Suggested SVN Changes:**

1. Enable Verbosity on the command like for all operations
2. Add error ENUM name to stderr
3. Add config flag for Serf Library debug logging.

Answer (score 2):

It still looks as it's either DNS resolution issue, certificate revocation list issue or (!) IPv6 issue. I can't provide you with a step-by-step solution however here is the list of things to check:

**DNS**

- Verify that the DNS resolution works correctly on affected machines (clients and servers),
- Verify that all involved machines have a PTR (reverse lookup zone) record on DNS and that these records are correct.

**Certificate**

- Does the delay reproduce over a plain HTTP?
- Do you have a *self-signed certificate* installed on SVN server? Is the certificate trusted on your network or signed by a certification authority?

**IPv6**

- Have you tried to disable IPv6 on a client and attempt to access the SVN server? Is there a delay in this case?

---

There is also another method that can help us to troubleshoot the delay:

You can enable low-level logging on Subversion client and attempt to reproduce the issue with a command-line client. Check the debug output on client and see when exactly does the delay occur. What happens before the delay and after it?

HOWTO enable client logging:

1. Add the following string to the `[global]` section of
   `%APPDATA%\subversion\servers` on your client's [server file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers):

   `neon-debug-mask = 395`
2. Reproduce the issue. See when the operations starts to 'lag' or intermittently stops (you should notice when the operation interrupts).

For further detail on neon-debug-mask please refer to [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html):

> neon-debug-mask
>
> This is an integer mask that the underlying HTTP library, Neon, uses
>   for choosing what type of debugging output to yield. The default value
>   is 0, which will silence all debugging output. For more information
>   about how Subversion makes use of Neon, see [Chapter 8, Embedding
>   Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.developer.html).

Comment: Some of these ideas I don't know how to try (like the DNS stuff) so I'll see if somebody in our company knows how to do that.  I tried the neon-debug-mask first but the collabnet log (assuming that is the correct log) doesn't seem to have anything extra since I updated the servers file.  I tried IPv6 on the client (Jenkins machine) and speeds were the same.  The certificate was issued by Global Sign.  I used IE to try to reproduce this but it was very quick (although it was just viewing).

Comment: According to our networking group DNS entries / lookups for these servers are configured and working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In our case I was using a checked-in svn.exe v1.6.5, which worked pretty well on my Windows 11 22H2, but apparently had some problems on the Windows Server 2015 build servers while retrieving/analyzing our certificate revocation list (CRL), which always caused 15+ seconds of delay. Switching to v1.9 fixed it.